# How to stop MySQL after entering $ ps -ef | grep mysql?

Tags: mysql, grep, ps

So I just uninstalled mysql (5.7.16) with homebrew on my mac, but when I entered

```
$ ps -ef | grep mysql
```

to check if there's any process running, I got this

```
"501  1069  1024   0 10:06AM ttys000    0:00.00 grep mysql"
```

Does this mean mysql is still running my computer? How can I uninstall mysql completely?

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: No, this means that your "grep command" is running, with the `mysql` parameter.

Comment: Please don't use the R tag unless your question involves the R language.

Comment: @sanastasiadis, you should post your comment as answer

Comment: what pid number is?

Answer (score 5):

The piped `grep` command filters all the lines that include the given keyword: `mysql`.

The `ps` command reports also your piped `grep` command currently running as a process.

The output you receive finally, means that the only running process having keyword `mysql` is your piped `grep` command with your `mysql` parameter.